# short way to ask for confirmation Java

Tags: java, validation, performance

I'm trying to find a way to ask the user a yes/no question that validates that the input is only yes (y/Y) or no (n/N). I'm trying to cut down on variables, while still keeping it readable. So far this is what I've come up with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputValidation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Do you wish to proceed? (Y/N): ");
            answer = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
            yesAnswer = answer.equals("Y");
        } while (answer.matches("[YN]"));

        if (yesAnswer)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not necessarily looking for the least amount of characters; more something that's short and flexible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, I would probably simply evaluate the input directly, before determing the actual result, for example

```
do {
    System.out.print("Do you wish to proceed? (Y/N): ");
    answer = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
} while (!answer.matches("[YN]"));
boolean yesAnswer = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
```

This basically waits until the `answer` matches `Y`, `N`, `y`, `n` before determine `yesAnswer`.  The next thing I might do is wrap it in method...

```
if (askYesNo("Do you wish to proceed? (Y/N): ")) {...
```

You could then go onto providing optional exit conditions to the method..

```
askYesNo("Delete all files [Ok/Cancel]", "(ok)?", "(cancel)?")
```

For example...

```
public class YesNo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (askYesNo("Do you wish to proceed? (Y/N): ")) {
            System.out.println("Okay...");
        }

        if (askYesNo("Delete all Files? (Okay/Cancel): ", "okay", "cancel")) {
            System.out.println("Make it so");
        }
    }

    public static boolean askYesNo(String question) {
        return askYesNo(question, "[Y]", "[N]");
    }

    public static boolean askYesNo(String question, String positive, String negative) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Convert everything to upper case for simplicity...
        positive = postive.toUpperCase();
        negative = negative.toUpperCase();
        String answer;
        do {
            System.out.print(question);
            answer = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
        } while (!answer.matches(positive) && !answer.matches(negative));
        // Assess if we match a positive response
        return answer.matches(positive);
    }
}
```

Comment: For additional options, within the method convert those params to `.toUpperCase` or `.toLowerCase` -- that way something funky like CaNcEl will still work. Right?

Comment: @mklein994 Yeah, I was thinking that to, maybe even seperating the "positive" and "negative" response as two parameters...

Comment: The question marks are just field delimiters, so I could use something like `.split("?")`

Comment: @mklein994 Of course you could simply compile your own `Pattern` configured to ignore the case ;)

Comment: @mklein994 But which are positive and which are negative response??